# Getting an eigenvector as a 'Vector<double>' listed from most significant to least using MathNet Numerics?

Tags: c#, vector, eigenvector, mathnet-numerics

I used the Evd<> class of MathNet Numerics to get the eigenvector of a matrix but it turned out to be of type `Vector<Complex>` and I was unable to cast that into `Vector<double>`, which is what I need for my operations.

This is how I got the eigenvector:

```
DenseMatrix processedData = someData;
Evd<> eigen = processedData.evd();
Vector<Complex> eigenvector = (Vector<Complex>)eigen.EigenValues;
```

When I tried casting as '`Vector<double>`' the program wouldn't accept it.
Is there a way to get the eigenvector of a matrix in `Vector<double>`?

Note: I had asked this question before, but had overlooked formatting my code so the `<double>` didn't appear and so the answers weren't what I was looking for.

Comment: What would the `double` value be? The magnitude of the complex number?

Answer (score 0):

An NxN real matrix will necessarily have N complex eigenvalues, of which anywhere from 1 to N will be real if N is odd, or 0 to N real if N is even.

To create a (possibly smaller) `Vector<double>` containing just the real eigenvalues from the vector of complex eigenvalues:

1. [Enumerate](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra/Vector%601.htm#Enumerate) through each [complex item](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Complex/Vector.htm#Item) in the vector.
2. Filter out all those that are not real by checking the [IsReal](http://iridium.mathdotnet.com/api/mathnet.numerics/complex.htm#IsReal) property.
3. For those that are real, extract the [Real](http://iridium.mathdotnet.com/api/mathnet.numerics/complex.htm#Real) component,
4. [Construct a new `DenseVector<double>`](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double/DenseVector.htm#OfEnumerable) from your enumerable.

(Alternatively you could create a `SparseVector<double>` of the same dimension with values only at locations corresponding to the real eigenvalues, if that would be more useful.  I'm not sure what you want to do with your eigenvalues.)